# Error when I run the SPDisposeChecker tool

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am getting the error "Disposable type not disposed Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb  ***This may be a false positive depending on how the type was created or if it is disposed outside the current scope".

Below is my code :

```
 public static int AddtoList( string title)
    {
        int returnValue = int.MinValue;
        SPUser sysAcount = SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers[@"SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM"];
        SPUserToken sysAcountToken = sysAcount.UserToken;
        using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url, sysAcountToken))
        {
                SPWeb currentWeb = siteCollection.RootWeb;
                SPList list = currentWeb.Lists[MyList];
                SPListItem newItem = errorList.Items.Add();  
                newItem[TitleColumnName] = title;
                currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                newItem.SystemUpdate(false);
                currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                returnValue = newItem.ID;

        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

I understood that when we use RootWeb we do not have dispose the object. Please let me know what does this error message mean and how do I correct it . I have several blogs bug failed to understand the error. Please help me.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/10/04/updated-spsite-rootweb-dispose-guidance.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the most up to date version of SPDisposeCheck?

An older version (Dec 2010?) incorrectly flagged .RootWeb

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/12/15/first-issue-with-spdisposecheck-has-been-identified-by-the-community.aspx

Comment: I have downloaded the version 12/13/2010 update: SPDisposeCheck v14.0.4762.1000. I could not find any other latest versions. I have also run the MSOCAF tool , it also shows the same error. How do I get it corrected.please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code sample for SPDisposeChecker error resolve.

```
     public static int AddtoList( string title) 
     {         
      int returnValue = int.MinValue; 
      SPUser sysAcount = SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers[@"SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM"];
      SPUserToken sysAcountToken = sysAcount.UserToken;
      using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url, sysAcountToken))
     { 
       //Add below code for dispose currentWeb object end of the functionality             
       using(SPWeb currentWeb = siteCollection.RootWeb)
       {
          SPList list = currentWeb.Lists[MyList];
          SPListItem newItem = errorList.Items.Add(); 
          newItem[TitleColumnName] = title; 
          currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true; 
          newItem.SystemUpdate(false);  
          currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false; 
          returnValue = newItem.ID;  
        }
      }        
      return returnValue;  
   }
```

Happy SharePointing !!!

Thanks,

Comment: RootWeb shouldn't be disposed. Golden rule: don't dispose object you didn't construct. You should dispose Web objects only if you called `SPSite.OpenWeb(...)`, or if you iterate over `SPSite.AllWebs` (which is weird I admit)